# For and while cycles examples for 12-13 years old class

Tags: for-loop, matrix, while-loop, octave

I teach in a secondary, first grade, school in Italy. The kids are 13 years old, on last year before second grade. I am teaching them the very basic of programming. Last year we did some flowcharts algorithms, this year we started code programming in Octave.
I've teached them how to make simple algorithms with if/else and now I'm going to go for the for and while cycles, but I struggle in finding exercises and examples which could be suitable for them, apart from cumulative sums/differences.
Consider that they are very young and have just basic math knowledge. They don't even know what a matrix is, but I can overcome that by explaining at least a monodimensional one.
But really I can use some help on exercise with for and while.
Any help?

Comment: You don’t need to iterate over a container (array) to make a loop useful. How about printing stuff to the screen? You can use a loop to repeat a certain character or a name a number of times. I think Logo was great to teach the concepts of programming without needing math just because of that.

Comment: My first software was Logo, indeed. Anyway, most of them are so skilled that just repeating a character would take about two minutes.

Comment: `while-loop` example:  Gaming Exercise: Ask the user to input a value.
while the input is incorrect. continue to 
ask the user to input another value.
Until they got it or exceed the `num_of_attempts`?

Comment: This is nice, thanks.

Comment: Hi Corrado, you might find more luck with this question at our sister site, [cseducators.se], which is more focused on how to teach students than Stack Overflow is.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'll post this there.